# Search and Replace HTML content in Wordpress

Tags: search, replace, wordpress

I've been trying to look for an answer to this for a while now, and would appreciate anyone's input regarding this.

I have some ad code on my site, hard coded into all 380+ posts on my website.  We recently had to go and change the ad to a different image.  Uh oh.  I thought it would be easy to just do a simple search and replace using https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/ - but unfortunately it doesn't find my HTML code that I'm trying to replace when using this method.

The HTML code I'd like to replace is:

```
<div id="insertPages_Content">
<div class="cols-wrapper cols-2">
<div class="col"><!-- Main_Ads_Shows -->
<div id="div-gpt-ad-1429121-0"><script type="mce-mce-mce-mce-text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1429121-0'); });
// ]]></script></div>
</div>
<div class="col nomargin"><!-- MainAds_Center -->
<div id="div-gpt-ad-1411-1"><script type="mce-mce-mce-mce-text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-112-1'); });
// ]]></script></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="cols-wrapper cols-2">
<div class="col"><!-- MainAds_Left -->
<div id="div-gpt-ad-14261-2"><script type="mce-mce-mce-mce-text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-19121-2'); });
// ]]></script></div>
</div>
<div class="col nomargin"><!-- MainAds_Right -->
<div id="div-gpt-ad"><script type="mce-mce-mce-mce-text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-14921-3'); });
// ]]></script></div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to replace that code with:

```
[insert page='/page' display='content']
```

Unfortunately, whenever I search for the original code, no plugin can find the code.  I then tried to download the .sql database and replace the content using a find and replace using a text editor, but no luck either.  Is there any way to do a search and replace of HTML content with wordpress?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You've got a lot of special characters in the code.  Search for it manually so that you know exactly what to look for--go through the sql database looking for a part of it like MainAds_Center.

That should show you where it's stored and what the string looks like as stored.

Then back up the sql database and write an instruction or script to update the database, changing that string.  (Or do it the way you described if the database isn't used much--once you know what to search for a find and replace on the database text will probably work.)